# Macro or formula to merge rows if has a merged cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I am trying to work out a formula or macro that would pickup to create 1 line when rows share a merged cell (see example in Column N). All other details are the same except columns L & N. Columns L & N would need to be added together to create the total value as well.

Although not all orders have a merged cell as well, some are just single lines

Columns A-K and O-Y are all the same data. Columns L & N have different data that need to be added together to total the amount whilst Column N is a merged cell across the rows with 1 number.

Although other lines will have all the columns with different data which means it needs to pick up the row on its own

[image]
*<sub>Click on image for larger view</sub>*

Comment: I did that but its still not in it

Comment: sorry just realised what you meant. I don't have an account there

Comment: The link was hiding in the question.  :-)

Comment: Will column N be the only place where there can potentially be merged cells, or can they be in other columns, also?

Comment: Only column N would have potential merged cell

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function SumByMerge(ColOffset As Integer) As Double
Dim OneCell As Range
SumByMerge = 0
For Each OneCell In Range(Range(Application.Caller.Address).MergeArea.Address)
    SumByMerge = SumByMerge + OneCell.Offset(0, ColOffset).Value
Next
End Function
```

and then

```
N2=SumByMerge(-1)
```

Remember - you must add checking that source cell values are numeric, and that the calculations do not go beyond the worksheet boundaries.

PS. If you enter the formula to a cell (N2), and THEN select and merge a region (N2:N3), Excel will NOT recalculate the function - it cannot detect that indirect source range was changed. Recalculate it manually.